# Spring Custom Authentication Manager

Tags: java, spring, security

I am using spring security for authenticating users. I have implemented custom authentication manager but get the credentials and name as blank in my authentication manager

Here is my security xml

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"
        ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <!-- <security:custom-filter after="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"
        ref="secureFilter" /> -->
    <security:session-management
        session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="ahcAuthenticationManager"     p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas">
```

Here is my Authentication manager code

```
public class AhcAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

private UserInfoService userInfoService;

public AhcAuthenticationManager(UserInfoService userInfoService) {
    this.userInfoService = userInfoService;
}

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println(arg.getName());
    if (userInfoService.authenticateUser(arg.getName(), arg
            .getCredentials().toString())) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(arg.getPrincipal(),
                arg.getCredentials());
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

The sysout in manager code always return empty
I am using jsf for client side and in my  managed bean inside request I can see those parameters in the request parameterMap
Any idea where i might be going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I figured it out its was my jsf form that was causing the problem. Used <h:form prependId="false">  and that did the trick. Jsf form prepends its own id to the field and hence the empty username and password